# Automapper exception: needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

Добрый день.С помощью automapper пытался проецировать функции разных типов моделей.Однако генерируется исключение(скриншот приложен).В интернете информации на этот счет не нашел, надеюсь поможете.

```
public UserDTO Get(Func<UserDTO, bool> predicate)
    {
        Mapper.Reset();
        Mapper.Initialize(conf => conf.CreateMap<Func<UserDTO, bool>, Func<User, bool>>());
        Func<User, bool> func = Mapper.Map<Func<User, bool>>(predicate);

        User user = database.Users.First(func);

        Mapper.Reset();
        Mapper.Initialize(conf => conf.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>());
        return Mapper.Map<UserDTO>(user);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй добавить конструктор без параметров для User

Comment: @SultanovShamil пробовал уже

Comment: @SultanovShamil да и проблема не в классах модели, а в самом делегате Func, у него нет конструкторов по умолчанию, следовательно маппить не удается.Альтернативу для него найти безуспешно

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой.
[Решил ее с помощью ссылки](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html)

Помогла замена

```
    Func<User, bool> func на
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> expfunc
```

На 6 AutoMapper работает.

Comment: правильная ссылка http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html